# repeated google maps script tag

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have developed a simple application with Google maps (API 3). This application loads a store's menu dynamically, so if the user click's a store item, the map shows the specific location of the store.

For that I have applied "Asynchronously Loading" from the [Developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API), it works perfectly, but I'am concern that every time the user click a store item (with out reloading the page), a script tag in the body is inserted.

[image]

Is it possible to have further problems because of that, performance , anything ?

Comment: It should be straightforward to prevent it loading more than once.

Comment: You didn't give any reason why you need to load the Maps API dynamically, so I'm going to assume you don't need that complication. Simply load the API once when your page is loaded, using an ordinary `<script>` tag without the `callback` parameter. Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: I have loaded the API dynamically because when I include it in the ordinary way and  try to set the center map option throws me the following error : google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor

Comment: I have made some changes in my javascript code and included with the ordinary script tag  and it works without loading it more than once. Thank you